# Cannot get TextLayoutCache value

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I've got an Android app that consumes a REST webservice that can return a large amount of data as a JSON string. The data is then displayed in its raw form in a TextView.

The app works fine when its a small amount of data, but for a large amount of data I get an error in LogCat that says "Cannot get TextLayoutCache value".

I know that it has to be something to do with space in the TextView but I'm wondering if anyone has any further knowledge so I can figure out the best way to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by specifying a maxLength for the TextView, e.g.:

android:maxLength="9000"

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to output a very large (~64K long) text string to WebView alert box.

Comment: From what I can tell, it just means you have too much text in a view.